# Why is my "getId" method of a simple object not marked as "not used" in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got a class in Android Java that's just a data container. I stripped it down to this:

```
public class Path {
    private final int mId;
    private final String mKey;

    public Path() {
        mId = 0;
        mKey = "";
    }

    public int getId() { return mId; }

    public String getKey() { return mKey; }
}
```

While `getKey` gets correctly marked as "not used" (grayed out), `getId` is not. I have not yet written code calling the function, and obviously I do not derive from a base class that has a method I could be overriding.

Is that a bug in the Android Studio because `getId` is often used in the Android framework, or is that method name some kind of java class keyword that should not be used for trivial getters?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the IDE. Just close the file and reopen it.

Comment: I tried closing AS but it won't go away. I assumed it might be a bug, but I wanted to make sure. Unfortunately searching for "Android getId" turns up a lot of results since it's a common method for user controls, so I can't really research on whether that is a special method like `public int hashCode`, which also won't get grayed out. But while `@Override` is accepted on `hashCode`, it is not on `getId`, so I am confused.

Comment: Same problem with Eclipse. Just ignore it.

Comment: I can confirm, this happens in my IDE too. When you right click the method and run "Find usages", it doesn't find anything. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: Maybe you have a custom adapter calling it.

Comment: If you mean the adapters for `ListView` etc., no, I hadn't when I wrote the question. And still don't have for other container classes where the same thing happens.

Comment: As u dint use the method getId() its showing like that.Its a bug in the IDE.